# Query string: Can a query string contain a URL that also contains query strings?

Tags: asp.net, html, iis

Example:

```
http://foo.com/generatepdf.aspx?u=http://foo.com/somepage.aspx?color=blue&size=15
```

I added the iis tag because I am guessing it also depends on what server technology you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'll probably want to UrlEncode the url that is in the query string.

Comment: I've found it's more reliable to Base64 encode the URL. I've run into issues concerning `+` and spaces being indistinguishable.

Answer (score 3):

The server technology shouldn't make a difference.

When you pass a value to a query string you need to [url encode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the name/value pair. If you want to pass in a value that contains a special character such as a question mark (?) you'll just need to encode that character as %3F. If you then needed to recursively pass another query string to the encoded url, you'll need to double/triple/etc encode the url resulting in the original ? turning into %253F, %25253F, etc.

Answer (score 1):

As reported in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

> W3C recommends that all web servers support semicolon separators in
>   addition to ampersand separators [(link reported on that wiki page)](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2) to allow
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded query strings in URLs within HTML
>   documents without having to entity escape ampersands.

So, I suppose the answer to the question is yes and you have to change in a ";" semicolon the "&" ampersand usaully used for key=value separator.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can, as far as I can tell, according to [RFC 3986: Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html) (from year 2005):

This is the BNF for [the query string](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#query):

```
query         = *( pchar / "/" / "?" )
pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
```

The spec says:

- *The characters slash ("/") and question mark ("?") may represent data within the query component*.
- *as query components are often used to carry identifying information in the form of "key=value" pairs and one frequently used value is a reference to another URI, it is **sometimes better for usability to avoid percent-encoding** those characters*

(But I suppose your server framework might or might not follow the specification exactly.)

Answer (score -1):

No, but you can encode the url and decode it later.